# Is the number of open sets same in homeomorphic topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology

Does the homeomorphic topological spaces, have same number of open sets?

Comment: If by 'number' you mean 'cardinality' then yes, since a homeomorphism induces a bijection on topologies. Otherwise 'number of open sets' only makes sense if the topology is finite, and that's almost never the case.

Comment: @Prometheus: And even in the finite case 'number' means the same as 'cardinality'.

Comment: @Frunobulax: Yes, Frunobulax, I am well aware that number means cardinality in the finite case. In the infinite case however, number means nothing. That is why I asked if akansha meant to write cardinality instead of number. If cardinality and number were completely unrelated it would not make sense for me to suggest replacing 'number' in the original question with 'cardinality'.